# Nginx settings for comet proxy?

Tags: nginx, comet

NGINX currently runs as a proxy for our application, but recently I implemented comet and `transfer-encoding: chunked`. I realized that NGINX is messing with the response by not properly sending back the contents and instead buffering the Comet.

What are the appropriate settings to make this work? Will it need to be URI-specific to not interfere with other requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with the following settings:

```
proxy_buffering      off;
proxy_connect_timeout       6000;
proxy_send_timeout          6000;
proxy_read_timeout          6000;
```